# GWT docklayoutpanel widget visibility

Tags: gwt, docklayoutpanel

How to know that a widget is hidden once you have call the

```
dock.setWidgetHidden(widget, true);
```

as it seems we do not have access to Layoutdata I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Using inheritance, you can extend DockLayoutPanel class and write an accessor to LayoutData, or just write a boolean method which tells if widget x is hidden or not.

Comment: Agreed but I was looking for a more standard solution withouth having to subclass a GWT component. I beleive this should be part of DLP API.

Comment: But according to http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html it isn't... Sorry about that. Maybe they had their own reason to set it as a protected inner class. Hopefully, GWT widget are really well designed in an OO sense (unlike GWT-Bootstrap). If you think other people might need it you can add a report here https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find something like this:

> String visibility = myDockLayoutPanel.getWidgetContainerElement(childPanel).getStyle().getVisibility()

The visibility might be "visible | hidden | collapse | inherit"

Comment: It seems that your solution returns "" wether it is visible or not.

Comment: ok, while this is my guess from the source code of DockLayoutPanel:570